# Sound coming from ear speaker only on Samsung S22

Tags: audio, speaker, loudspeaker

My Samsung S22 currently has a weird issue since a few days ago where any sound is currently only output via the ear speaker. During calls the sound output is very quiet on the ear speaker, people's voices are almost inaudible, while music and video sound are output via the ear speaker at the highest volume. There is no sound coming from the regular speakers anymore at all.

I haven't (knowingly) messed around with any of the audio settings before this happened. **Outputting audio via Bluetooth speakers works just fine.**

What I've tried to solve this, but to no avail, is the following:

- Restart phone (several times)
- Connect and disconnect Bluetooth speakers
- Turn mono output on and off in the accessibility settings
- Use a [Speaker Cleaner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speaker.cleaner.fixer.sound.booster.fixmyspeaker) app
- Carefully shake phone to make sure nothing has come loose
- Started device in Safe Mode, but no audio playing from speakers either

I am very careful in handling my phone, it doesn't have any scratches, dents or whatsoever, because I never drop it. It's not the result of dropping the phone or hitting it hard against something.

The phone is running on

- Android 13.0
- One UI 5.1
- Build number TP1A.220624.014.S901BXXS6CWH6
- Security Patch from September 1st, 2023

What could be causing this? Is this a software or hardware issue?

Comment: I'm not talking about external speakers, the problem is with the built-in speakers of the phone.

Comment: I am aware of that. The problem is with the built-in speakers and I only tried Bluetooth to check if it's some volume setting. Also, enabling and disabling Bluetooth speakers was an attempt to reset the audio driver to use the built-in speakers.

Comment: I've also tried the safe mode, but no audio is playing in safe mode, either.

Comment: Yes, that's my assumption, too. I still have a warranty on the device with my mobile provider. If this doesn't get solved and a software issue is ruled out in the next days, I'll request a replacement device. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a hardware defect, the device will be replaced as it's still inside of the warranty.